# iOS TextField's secureTextEntry cause keyboard problem

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

If I set textField's secureTextEntry to true, the keyboard can't change input anymore.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Show code - do you set it programatically to true and afterwards does it stop working?

Comment: YES! I set it to true programatically. After the keyboard show, I can't change input.

Comment: Again - show the code? When do you set it programatically? PS I *suspect* the trouble is that you set it in the wrong place. Maybe set it in storyboard or e.g. viewDidLoad as a test and see how it goes.